# can we Use vrealize log insight instead of Splunk for small Jobs?

Tags: vmware, splunk, vmware-server, vmware-tools

1. methods to get data into the Vrealize log insight?
2. restricted on pulling data from?
3. restrict on data permission in Vrealize log insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Syslog and the Log Ingestion API
2. No restrictions. If you can send it through either option from #1, then Log Insight can receive it.
3. Yes, through the use of datasets.

All of this information is easily available through the Log Insight documentation page, mainly the administration guide: https://docs.vmware.com/en/vRealize-Log-Insight/index.html